# jQuery this not working with my code

Tags: jquery, this

I have the following markup;

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="expand">Showroom area - New Display Zone</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td class="shortfall">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>Core Display</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>R8</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>Highlight Car</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="expand">Showroom - Handover Bay</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td class="shortfall">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>Core Display</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>R8</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>Highlight Car</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $('td.expand').click(function () {

        $(this).parents().siblings('tr.hidden').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

I want this code to toggle the first 3 tr.hidden classes as the relate directly to the first td.expand class, but running the code toggles all tr.hidden classes to show.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you're doing wrong is not telling jQuery you only want to process *some* of the `tr.hidden` elements. You're also using `parents` (plural) where you almost certainly want `parent` (singular).

You can use `nextUntil` to gather elements until a condition matches. In this case, you can use `nextUntil` to gather rows until you find a row that isn't `tr.hidden`. So:

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil(':not(tr.hidden)').toggle();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/etixef) | [source](http://jsbin.com/etixef/edit)

---

Alternately — and this would be my preferred solution — you might consider changing your structure somewhat, and using multiple `tbody` elements, one for each of these expand/collapse groups:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand">...</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
  ...
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand">...</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
  ...
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

That simplifies things rather markedly:

```
$(this).closest('tbody').find('tr.hidden').toggle();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ofeqah/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ofeqah/2/edit)

Comment: +1, but if there were to be elements that don't match `.hidden` between the `.expand` elements this wouldn't work. You could use the second argument to `nextUntil` instead, to filter the matched selection to only include elements matching `.hidden`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Seems to work fine with the given structure, which I suspect is fairly regular (summary row followed by details row followed by summary row followed by details row).

Comment: Agreed, it would work fine with the structure in the question. I was just pointing out that if that were to change (perhaps another row after the summary row, but before the `.hidden` rows) then your example wouldn't work, but `nextUntil('.expand', '.hidden')` would.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Except that the `expand` class is on the `td`, not the `tr`. But `.nextUntil('tr:has(td.expand)', '.hidden')` would work, thanks, useful to know. For this sort of thing, I'd definitely lean toward multiple `tbody` elements, though. I love having containers for this stuff. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, that'll teach me to read the code properly! And yeah, I like your `tbody` solution best too :)

Comment: T.J. Crowder - That mostly worked for me, although I did have to change it slightly to get the code to run -   `code` $(this).parent().nextUntil(':not(tr.hidden)').toggle();

Comment: @webworker: That's exactly the line of code in the answer, I'm not seeing what you changed...?

Comment: @webworker: Ah, okay. I did drop you a note on the question to let you know I'd found that error. :-)

Comment: No worries. Your original code got me close enough, allowing a little trial and error to finally get it working. Appreciate the prompt assistance though..

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `parent()` and not `parents()`